# Where is path of "gpu/mxGPUArray.h" file?

Tags: c++, matlab

Where is path of "gpu/mxGPUArray.h" file?

I'm trying to use mexcuda to compile a .cu file. I must include "gpu/mxGPUArray.h" to code. But I can not find the path of this header in my computer to add it's path to my project.

Note that i'm using matlab2020, and Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `mexcuda` command-line tool to compile your `.cu` MEX file, you do not need to specify the include paths directly - the tool sets this up for you. See the [`mexcuda` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/mexcuda.html) for more.

If you need the path for an IDE integration, it's in `<matlabroot>/toolbox/parallel/gpu/extern/include`.